# VB.net Create Date Killswitch (Compare two Dates)

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I'd like to implement a killswitch based on a date into my app, so that it'll stop working by a certain time. Therefore I figured out on date (eg. 1st of February 2019). Once the date of the system (where my app is running on) is greater than the Killswitch date, I want it to stop working. I tried:

```
If Today.Date.toString() >= "02/01/2019" Then
End
Else
...
```

That didn't work. The problem I have is that the date format is different on each computer, some have **MM/dd/YYYY**, some **dd/MM/YYYY** and some **YYYY/MM/dd**. Is it still possible to convert all dates to a universal format and compare them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the dates are a standard format you can use DateTime.Parse.  At that point you will compare two DateTime values and then the greater than or equal to will work.

```
If DateTime.Now >= DateTime.Parse("02/01/2019") Then
    Environment.End
End If
```

In order to parse the date manually, you'll need to know which format it's in because you would be required to create the DateTime object from it's pieces.  Here's an example:

```
Dim strDate As String = "12/28/2018"
Dim year As Integer = Integer.Parse(strDate.Substring(6, 4))
Dim month As Integer = Integer.Parse(strDate.Substring(0, 2))
Dim day As Integer = Integer.Parse(strDate.Substring(3, 2))
Dim d = New DateTime(year, month, day)
```

Comment: Noted, they will still need to know what format it's in.  Added an example that parses one of the formats specified.

Answer (score 2):

Don't hard-code your date; then the format won't be an issue.  Instead, use the constructor of the [DateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_DateTime__ctor_System_Int32_System_Int32_System_Int32_) class to create your kill target with your specific year, month, and day:

```
Dim targetDT As New DateTime(2019, 2, 1)
If DateTime.Today > targetDT Then
    ' ... do something in here ...
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
    Dim currentDate As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    If currentDate.Month >= 2 And currentDate.Day >= 1 And currentDate.Year >= 2019
          End
    End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, comments and explanations in-line.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    If DateTime.Now > ExpireDate Then
        MessageBox.Show("Your trial period has expired")
        Close()
    End If
End Sub

Private ExpireDate As Date

Private Sub OPCode3()
    'run once at first startup
    'Store As DateTime, then you can compare DateTime withour converserion or parsing
    ExpireDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3)
End Sub
```